# Create Space Time Cube From Multidimensional Raster Layer tool missing from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, space-time-cube

The tool is listed as part of the 'Space Time Pattern Mapping' toolbox, and I can see the other tools within the toolbox, but 'Create Space Time Cube From Multidimensional Raster Layer' does not appear and I cannot search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are using a version earlier than ArcGIS Pro 2.5.

As you can see on the [Space Time Pattern Mining toolbox history](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/space-time-pattern-mining-toolbox-history-pro.htm) page that tool was only added at that version.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.3 and, when I use the Geoprocessing pane to search for it, I find it to be present.